# How to detect file update when using remote_file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using remote_file in a for loop to go through deployment files (specified in node attributes). I verify given checksum (sha256sum) to see whether already existing files are same or not; if not, I update them; if same, it simply skips.

I need to know , in the recipe, whether any file was updated or not so that I restart app server in case of any file changed under deployments directory.

Is there any default attribute that I can use (which tells all file updates were skipped) or alternatively what is the best approach to have it done?

Thanks,

```
node['app']['deployments'].each do |file, value|  
    remote_file "/apps/deployments/#{value['file-name']}" do  
        source   "file:///tmp/deployments/#{value['file-name']}"  
        checksum value['check-sum']
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the concept of [notifications](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications) in Chef, which helps you in this case:

```rb
node['app']['deployments'].each do |file, value|  
    remote_file "/apps/deployments/#{value['file-name']}" do  
        source    "file:///tmp/deployments/#{value['file-name']}"  
        checksum  value['check-sum']
        notifies  :restart, 'service[appserver]'
    end 
end 

service "appserver"
```

As long as you don't supply a `:immediately` parameter to `notifies`, chef-client will queue up all notifications and execute them (aka restart the service) *once* at the end of the chef run.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to know whether any file was updated or not and restart only if one of the files was updated

Comment: Chef will do that automatically. If no file is updated, it will never notify the `service` resource. If all files were updated, it will notify it multiple times, but restart only once in the end.

Comment: In other words: Notifications are only triggered, if the resource is updated (in your case: the file changes).